# Error Installing ORACLE EBS on LINUX server

Tags: java, linux, oracle, unix

I encounter below error when starting using the EBS installer :

```
[root@S41BF069 rapidwiz]# ./rapidwiz


Rapid Install Wizard is validating your file system......
4 dvd labels found
Rapid Install Wizard will now launch the Java Interface.....

[root@S41BF069 rapidwiz]# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /EBS/startCD/Disk1/rapidwiz/jre/Linux_x64/1.6.0/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.DebugHelper.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Xext is X windows extensions. A quick google seems tgo say you need to install the libxext-dev package to get the lib.

Comment: ok... but have dependencies package.                               [root@S41BF069 install_rpm]# rpm -hiv libXext-devel-1.3.1-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
warning: libXext-devel-1.3.1-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        pkgconfig(x11) is needed by libXext-devel-1.3.1-2.el6.x86_64
        pkgconfig(xextproto) is needed by libXext-devel-1.3.1-2.el6.x86_64

Comment: What is your linux distro and version?